# Memory leak due to using retain properties

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

In almost all my classes I use properties and I always use retain properties like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) HomeViewController *homeViewController;
```

And in the implementation file I instantiate these properties like this:

```
self.homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc]init];
```

and this is the only place I am releasing:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [homeViewController release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Am I correct in believing that I have a memory leak here - because the retain count will actually be 2.  The first comes from the property retain and the second comes from the alloc call?

If yes, should I be using assign under these circumstances?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you have a leak, and yes your retain count is 2.

Three solutions:

- `self.homeViewController = [[[HomeViewController alloc]init] autorelease];`
- `homeViewController = [[[HomeViewController alloc]init];`
- `UIViewController *temp = [[HomeViewController alloc]init]; self.homeViewController = temp; [temp release];`

Comment: There is already a good answer there. You should use retain, you should make them properties and you should release them in your dealloc and viewDidUnload methods.

Comment: Dont use the setter methods from -init or -dealloc. Just access the ivar directly.

Comment: @fakeAccount22: not always an option. For instance, with synthesized properties, you can now 'omit' the ivar declaration, and with an nice gcc bug, you can't access it from derived classes, although you should...

Comment: @jv42 - so another option would be so simply use assign instead of retain correct?

Comment: @TheLearner: yes and no. You should never use assign for IBOutlet properties (bug/leak source). And it's not right conceptually. You *should* retain it because you want to keep it for the lifetime of your owning object.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you do have a memory leak.  It could be corrected as follows:

```
self.homeViewController = [[[HomeViewController alloc]init] autorelease];
```

Synthesizing a property that is retained creates a setter that effectiveley does the following:

```
- (void)setHomeViewController(HomeViewController *)aHomeViewController
{
    if (![homeViewController isEqual:aHomeViewController]) {
        [homeViewController release];
        homeViewController = aHomeViewController;
        [homeViewController retain];
    }
}
```

The synthesized setter releases the old value of the property, and retains the new value.  Your alloc'ed variable thus gets retained twice: in the alloc & in the property setter.  Then, it gets released only once, in the dealloc.

Note:  I corrected the above code as per jv42 and JeremyP's comments.  The synthesized setter first effectively checks that the new value and the old value don't point to the same object.  Without checking for that (as I had it originally) it could release the HomeViewController object, and lose it, before setting the property.

Comment: Precision: it checks whether it is different before doing anything else.

Comment: Yeah, but there is different information that wasn't included in your response, so I went ahead with the post.  Along with your three well formed solutions, a more complete picture is given.

Comment: Comment on the logical side behind this, equally applicable to other answers I guess: when you do alloc/init you have an owning reference. You then use a setter, which is conceptually a closed box. So what the setter does is irrelevant — the point is that you've done everything you wanted with the object so you no longer want to own it. Hence you should release it, or just throw it onto the autorelease pool at creation if you prefer the semantics of an object you explicitly don't mean to own.

Comment: @Tommy: if that were an answer I would vote for it, it has the best explanation.

Comment: @salo.dm: @jv42 is not talking about the difference between your response and his but the fact that your hypothetical setter implementation is wrong.  If homeViewController and aHomeViewController are pointers to the same object, your version could cause aHomeViewController to get deallocated.

Comment: @salo.dm when is it autoreleased?

Comment: @jv42, @JeremyP: Thanks for the correction.  Very important distinction! I edited my response to fix that.  If you see any other problems, please let me know to re-edit.

Comment: @TheLearner: as jv42 noted, properties are released in -dealloc and, for view controllers, also in -viewDidUnload

Comment: @TheLearner: in other words, an object generally retains its own properties as long as it exists.  Once the object is released, dealloc is called, and it releases its properties.  That's why retained properties are released in dealloc and don't have to be released anywhere else.  Hope this helps clarify any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `self.yourObject = nil`; in `viewDidUnload` method.

Comment: No. 1. This does nothing to fix the leak caused by the +2 `retainCount` caused by the OP's code. 2. This might suggest a fundamental misunderstanding of the purpose of `viewDidUnload`: This method is only called when `didReceiveMemoryWarning` is invoked while this view has been pushed down the stack, for example, by some subsequent view controller; `viewDidUnload` is called to let the view controller know that its view has been removed and let's it clean up any references it might be maintaining to that view. But it should _not_ be used for routine cleanup when a view controller is dismissed.

Comment: @Rob any citation to support that `viewDidUnload` is not supposed to be used for routine cleanup?

Comment: @jv42 The "Memory Management" section of the [UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) describes the purpose of `didReceiveMemoryWarning` vs `viewDidLoad`. Also refer to `viewDidUnload` in the [iOS 6.0 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html), in which iOS 6 makes this more explicit. You certainly can clean up non-UI stuff in `viewDidUnload`, but I personally don't think that this is what is was designed for.

Comment: @jv42 Also, going back to the fundamental question, it would be easy to conclude from the name of the [`viewDidUnload`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidUnload) method, that it's called whenever the view is released. It's not. If you read the docs carefully (or `NSLog` when it's called), you'll see that `viewDidUnload` is _not_ called when a view is released because you dismissed it. It is only called in low memory situations.

Comment: @Rob Ok, it wasn't clear for me from your comment that you did not include UI stuff as frowned-upon. For me `viewDidUnload` should mirror `viewDidLoad`, and putting everything (including Model data) in these methods doesn't make sense.

Comment: @jv42 I was just reacting to the implication of raaz's comment that you put routine cleanup stuff in `viewDidUnload`. Some newer developers don't appreciate that it is only called in those rare low memory situations. Routine cleanup should be in `dealloc`.

Comment: From the link you sent: "If this happens, it also calls the viewWillUnload and viewDidUnload methods to give your code a chance to relinquish ownership of any objects that are associated with your view hierarchy, including objects loaded from the nib file, objects created in your viewDidLoad method, and objects created lazily at runtime and added to the view hierarchy." This isn't very restrictive.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16782/discussion-between-rob-and-jv42)